# How do i clean out first input from the loop to calculate properly for the second input?

Tags: c

Apparently, I'm running a program, it should create a restaurant, including menu, customer, report, etc.

So I was doing the customer function first, and I have it looping (customer 1,customer2,customer3) but after I'm finished with customer 1 (calculating the total for cus1), I continued the loop and proceeded to customer 2. But this issue came up, my customer 2's total was mixed up with customer 1's (just to better clarify,customer2's total was cus1+cus2 but I only wanted customer2's)

Just so if anyone knows, please give me a guide, would be appreciated, thanks!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#define COMBOA 8.50
#define COMBOB 10.50
#define COMBOC 18.00
#define COMBOD 32.50

void main()
{
    void logo();
    void menu();
    char cus();

    logo();
    menu();
    cus();

    system("pause");
}

void logo() //Restaurant's logo
void menu() //Restaurant's menu

char cus()
{
    char combo;
    double total, combo1, total2 = 0;
    int quan, cus = 1;

    do
    {
        printf("Customer No: %d\n\n", cus);
        ++cus;

        do {
            printf("Please select Combo A/B/C/D (Enter 'X' to exit) : ");
            scanf(" %c", &combo);
            fflush(stdin);

            if (combo == 'X' || combo == 'x')
                break;
            printf("Quantity : ");
            scanf(" %d", &quan);

            switch (combo) //about the combo prices

            total = (double)quan * combo1;
            total2 += total;

            if (combo != 'A' && combo != 'a' && combo != 'B' && combo != 'b' && combo != 'C' && combo != 'c' && combo != 'D' && combo != 'd')
                total2 == total;

            printf("\t\tCOMBO %c : %d @ RM%.2f = RM %.2f\n", combo, quan, combo1, total);
     } while (combo != 'X' || combo != 'x');

        printf("\t\tTOTAL AMOUNT PURCHASED = RM %.2f\n", total2);

 return 0;
```

}

Comment: Probably a typo here `total2 == total;` might want to be `total2 = total;`

Comment: I think your code is not complete. The inner do{} is not ended. Also you are doing total2 == total (I believe it should be total2 = total). The switch(combo) seems to be incomplete

Comment: @cleblanc thanks! changed it

Comment: @StoogyI only uploaded part of the code because the full one is too long, everything is fine just that my total seems to be messed up. tried thinking about using flash but I don't think it would still work.

Comment: You should definitely post a MCVE if you want people here to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have variables that will be reset on each iteration of the loop and then only used within the same iteration before they are reset again. Declare those inside the loop, or better yet, inside the block where they are used.

In this case, that would be the block containing the `scanf()` statements that set them.

(By the way, code dealing with dollars and cents always uses fixed-point, not 32-bit floating-point, to avoid round-off errors.)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (combo != 'A' && combo != 'a' ...)
           total2 == total;
```

Does not affect anything to `total2`. Replace it by 'total2= total;'